# getCurrentPosition not firing callbacks

Tags: javascript, api, callback, geolocation

I'm trying to grab the latitude and longitude of visitors to my site. However, for some reason, I'm not getting anything from getCurrentPosition().

Here is my current code:

```
const successCb = (position) => {
    console.log(position);
}

const errorCb = (error) => {
    console.error(error);
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCb, errorCb);
});
```

So from my understanding, this should either log the getCurrentPosition info (including lat and long) or an error to the console. But I think getCurrentPosition() isn't even firing the callbacks (successCb and errorCb). No console log, no error. I have location services on, I can get navigator.geolocation logged, and I'm on https://. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I noticed when I tried that a little icon showed in my browser location bar. When I clicked it, I was told that location services was disabled on my computer - could that be what's happening to you? I didn't get any errors in my console.

Comment: Yeah I have that too but for me it says that location services are on. Also, I don’t get an error either I just don’t get anything haha

Answer (score 0):

```js
const successCb = (position) => {
    console.log('in success callback');
    console.log(position);
}

const errorCb = (error) => {
    console.log('in error callback');
    console.error(error);
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log('in load listener');
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        console.log('geolocation available');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCb, errorCb);
    }
    else {
        console.log('geolocation not available');
    } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
</head>

<body>
    <h3>example</h3>
</body>
<html>
```